# How to add specific number of empty rows in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-insert

I have a `SQLite` file and I want to add `2550 empty (NULL)` rows.

I am able to add one empty line with this code

```
INSERT INTO my_table DEFAULT VALUES
```

But I need 2550 rows. Is there any shortcut for it? I don't want to execute same code 2550 times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your version of SQLite support it, you could use a recursive CTE to generate a series from 1 to 2550, and then insert "empty" records along that sequence:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE generate_series(value) AS (
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value + 1
    FROM generate_series
    WHERE value + 1 <= 2550
)

INSERT INTO yourTable (col1, col2, ...)
SELECT NULL, NULL, ...
FROM generate_series;
```

It is not clear which values, if any, you want to specify for the actual insert.  If you omit mention of any column in the insert, then by default SQLite should assign `NULL` or whatever default value be defined for that column.

Comment: That it's worked, thanks a lot Tim. You make my works easy.

Comment: Happy to help you `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

If your table is empty, then use a recursive `CTE` to get 2550 rows each consisting of the integers 1 to 2550 and use them to insert 2550 rows:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 1 nr
  UNION ALL
  SELECT nr + 1
  FROM cte
  WHERE nr < 2550
)
INSERT INTO my_table(rowid)
SELECT nr FROM cte
```

This way, you use the column [`rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) where the integer values of the `CTE` will be stored  and there is no need to enumerate all the columns of your table in the `INSERT` statement.
 These columns will get their default values.

If your table is not empty you can do it in a similar way by starting the integer numbers from the max `rowid` value in the table +1:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT MAX(rowid) + 1 nr FROM my_table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT nr + 1
  FROM cte
  WHERE nr < (SELECT MAX(rowid) + 2550 FROM my_table)
)
INSERT INTO my_table(rowid)
SELECT nr FROM cte
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=43e2e06c55e7119f14207854feac8133) (for 5 rows).

But since you also tagged `android-sqlite` you can use a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 2550; i++) {
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO my_table DEFAULT VALUES");
}
```

where `db` is a valid non null instance of `SQLiteDatabase`.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate numbers using a recursive CTE and then insert . . . but you need to be more explicit about the values being inserted:

```
with cte as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from cte
      where n < 2550
     )
insert into mytable (<something>)
    select <something>
    from cte;
```

I think you need to specify the value for at least one column in SQLite.