# How to generate N random values with SELECT?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

With SQL you can write the following query:

```sql
SELECT RANDOM();
```

What if I want multiple random rows? I tried:

```sql
SELECT RANDOM() LIMIT 42;
```

Apparently it doesn't work. I really can't find anything on Duck/SO.

Comment: What is your version of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: Postgres and SQLite. I haven't decide which I'll use eventually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add specific number of empty rows in sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65439177/11683)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select multiple rows you need a way to generate them.  That requires a `from` clause.

In Postgres, this is particularly easy using `generate_series()`:

```
select random()
from generate_series(1, 42);
```

Most databases (including Postgres) you could also use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select random() as val, 1 as lev
      union all
      select random(), lev + 1
      from cte
      where lev < 42
     )
select *
from cte;
```